# forward declaration of using in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, forward-declaration

I'm trying to use a type alias of an object in another header without including header file .

My simplified version of code is :

```
// A.h
    #include <vector>
    using Vector=std::vector<int>;

====================================================

//B.h
using Vector;//forward declaration but not working !(Vector has not beed declared)
int foo(Vector*);

====================================================
//B.cpp
#include "A.h"
void foo(Vector*){}
```

I don't want to write `using Vector=std::vector<int>;` again in `B.h` because It's definition must be same as definition of `Vector` in `A.h` and It may change in **future** and I can't include it because my code have **circular dependency**.

Is forward declaration of `using` possible in c++11 ?

Comment: You need to `#include "A.h"` in `B.h`.

Comment: @juanchopanza It has circular dependency . so I can't do that

Comment: In a word, no. Instead of repeating the declaration, factor it out to a separate header and include in both A and B.

Comment: You can't forward declare `typedef`s (your `using` is just a `typedef`).

Comment: Why don't you fix the question to show that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible, however the following could be a workaround.

```
// Common.h
...
#include <vector>
using Vector=std::vector<int>;
...
```

Afterwards you include `Common.h` in both, `A.h` and `B.h`.